# Scroll then fixed sidebar content disappears on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a right side bar that scrolls to the end of the content then fixes, however on scrolling up occasionally the content disappears. Is there a way to make the content "fix" to the top of the side bar on scroll up? I'm using Bootstrap 3 and have recreated this here in Bootply (http://www.bootply.com/mbjviJQBxv) and here is the script I've adapted courtesy of Ryan Maxwell:

```
$(function() {

var $window = $(window);
var lastScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
var wasScrollingDown = true;

var $sidebar = $(".rightSideBar");
if ($sidebar.length > 0) {

    var initialSidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top;

    $window.scroll(function(event) {

        var windowHeight = $window.height();
        var sidebarHeight = $sidebar.outerHeight();

        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var scrollBottom = scrollTop + windowHeight;

        var sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top;
        var sidebarBottom = sidebarTop + sidebarHeight;

        var heightDelta = Math.abs(windowHeight - sidebarHeight);
        var scrollDelta = lastScrollTop - scrollTop;

        var isScrollingDown = (scrollTop > lastScrollTop);
        var isWindowLarger = (windowHeight > sidebarHeight);

        if ((isWindowLarger && scrollTop > initialSidebarTop) || (!isWindowLarger && scrollTop > initialSidebarTop + heightDelta)) {
            $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
        } else if (!isScrollingDown && scrollTop <= initialSidebarTop) {
            $sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
        }

        var dragBottomDown = (sidebarBottom <= scrollBottom && isScrollingDown);
        var dragTopUp = (sidebarTop >= scrollTop && !isScrollingDown);

        if (dragBottomDown) {
            if (isWindowLarger) {
                $sidebar.css('top', 0);
            } else {
                $sidebar.css('top', -heightDelta);
            }
        } else if (dragTopUp) {
            $sidebar.css('top', 0);
        } else if ($sidebar.hasClass('fixed')) {
            var currentTop = parseInt($sidebar.css('top'), 10);

            var minTop = -heightDelta;
            var scrolledTop = currentTop + scrollDelta;

            var isPageAtBottom = (scrollTop + windowHeight >= $(document).height());
            var newTop = (isPageAtBottom) ? minTop : scrolledTop;

            $sidebar.css('top', newTop);
        }

        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
        wasScrollingDown = isScrollingDown;
    });
}
```

I've searched Stack Overflow for a solution, but can't find one, I'm a newbie in scripting and appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just CSS

```
.rightSideBar{
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
}
```

Take a look at this in Bootply http://www.bootply.com/1vcS8aufxj

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Gravesy and sorry for the delay in replying, I've had some computer issues.

Comment: No worries - if my answer helped could you please mark it as the correct answer please.